# Filter based on a amount of object returned by another query in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two classes in my model `Painting` and `Hit`.

```
class Painting(models.Model):
    objectNumber = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Hit(models.Model):
    painting = models.ForeignKey(Painting)
```

In this way, each painting can be connected to multiple hits, but each hit can only be connected to one painting.

I wish to select each painting that's connected to 3 or less hits. How can I do this?

*Possible solutions:*

I figured I could do some sort of for loop...

```
for painting in Painting.objects.all():
    if len(Hit.objects.filter(painting=painting)) > 4:
        # and then append it to a list or something
```

... but I assume there's some native filter I can apply that I can't seem to find. Or else I could add a field to `Painting` to count how many hits are related to it, but that seems illogical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) for this. For this you have to declare a related_name for you `Hit` model

```
class Hit(models.Model):
    painting = models.ForeignKey(Painting, related_name='paintings')
```

Then use select related on the painting model

```
Painting.objects.all().select_related('painting')
```

This will give you the queryset. Now you can apply any operation like `len` or `count` but no need to loop now. for your case you can chain any annotate or filter to count number of hits.

NOTE: If you have ManyToMany fields instead of foreign key fields then [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) would do the trick.

Comment: select_related only works for onetoone and foreignkeyfield. You have to go for prefetch_related if you have manytomany field

Comment: I can't seem to get it right. I run `Painting.objects.all().prefetch_related('paintings')` which returns an `AttributeError: Cannot find 'paintings' on Painting object, 'paintings' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`

Comment: why prefetch related ? you have foreign keys so you have to use select_related

Comment: I'm also trying it for a ManyToMany field : `painting = models.ManyToManyField(Painting,blank=True,related_name='paintings')`

Comment: lets continue this in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149497/chat-room

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at queryset annotations. You can annotate the number of hits for each painting, then filter paintings based on their number of hits ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations)).

```py
from django.db.models import Count

Painting.objects.annotate(num_hits=Count('hit')).filter(num_hits__lte=3)
```